# How can I get the set difference of two Sparse Matrices?

Tags: python, matrix, set

I have two matrices A and B. I want to find the set difference between them: the set of all elements that are in A but not in B. The resulting matrix has to be of the same shape, so another way of putting it is that elements that are found in both A and B have to be set to zero. For example, with the following matrices:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

A = csr_matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
B = csr_matrix([[6, 0, 7, 0, 9]])
```

The result would be:

```
C = [[0, 2, 0, 4, 0]]
```

So far, I've been trying to work with python's set difference function:

```
def set_difference(a,b):
    a = set(a)
    b = set(b)
    c = a.difference(b)
    return c
```

However this isn't working - it doesn't seem like a csr_matrix can be turned into a set. So if I'm not using sets, how could I get the set difference of two matrices?

Comment: Most everything in python is boolean-like.  :)  That is, you can evaluate numbers and strings as true/false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using normal matrices, not sparse matrices.  Based on your problem description, the following would work:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
B = [6, 0, 7, 0, 9]
C = [A[i] if not B[i] else 0 for i in range(len(A))]
```

Anything non-zero evaluates to "true", so this creates a list of all A[i] values when B[i] is zero for the same index, otherwise it populates a zero for that index.

EDIT: Try this syntax with csr_matrices:

```
 C = csr_matrix([A[0,i] if not B[0,i] else 0 for i in range(A.size)])
```

EDIT2: for 2D sparse matrices, use this:

```
 C = csr_matrix( [ [A[i,j] if not B[i,j] else 0 for i in range(A.shape[0]) ] for j in range(a.shape[1]) ])
```

Comment: A csr_matrix is a type of Sparse Matrix. Using your solution raises the following error:
TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]

Comment: What I'm saying is that it doesn't look like you need a sparse matrix.  csr_matrix([1,2,3,4,5]) is functionally equivalent to scipy.array([1,2,3,4,5]).  Is this a simple example of a larger problem?

Comment: Yes, the example I'm giving is simply a toy example. With the data I'm dealing with, I have to use sparse matrices.

Comment: Is your matrix 2D?  If so, I need to mod the example again.

Comment: Your solution did the trick! :) I used .get_shape()[1] for the size and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the `csr_matrix` fits into it but you could just use a mask on the A:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

A = csr_matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
B = csr_matrix([[6, 0, 7, 0, 9]])
_A = A.toarray()
_B = B.toarray()


_A[_B != 0] = 0

print(_A)
[[0 2 0 4 0]]
```

Comment: This would work on a small matrix, but the problem with toarray() is that it stores everything in memory, which may not be possible for a larger matrix.

Comment: @kormak well it will be a lot faster than using python loops. where is th data coming from?

Comment: Also how did you think creating two sets then a third would take less memory than this approach?